# Will uploading the images on my site via a third party effect my reputation and rankings?

Tags: google, images

I am developing an entertainment related website. I am planning to upload posters of movies & TV episodes on third party sites like `imgur.com` & `tinypic.com`.  Then I will post the link of that image on my website.

Will doing so hurt my site in terms of reputation, publicity, or Google rankings?

Comment: Do you mean that your site will load the images from these other sites when a user visits??

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means they don't want to host the images on their website themselves.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but, I'd recommend using Google Picasa instead of imgur or TinyPic. You can do the same thing, but the images aren't public.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on all the media (like posters) you upload to the 3rd party sites as well as the permissions associated with it.

If you're uploading copyrighted material that you don't have rights to publish to the web, then its going to be bad referencing that material as your own.

If you upload the material (with the author's permission) to the third party site, make sure you credit the author when linking to the material.

If you upload material, and claim it your own and/or use it in a manner the material's author does not approve of, then you could get sued and/or reported to various companies which could even include the search engines.

So my suggestion is get permission first from the authors of each poster you want to upload before continuing.